# Regex pattern for finding a String contains some words AND doesn't have some other words

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-negation

I'm using Java regex util to create a program and now I need to find some strings which have some words and doesn't have other one.

For example:

I want to find String which has 'for' and remove everything after it, but if the string has 'centre for', we do nothing.

There are some sentences which I want to check:

`1. This program for all people` => This program (remove everything after 'for')

`2. Centre for Effective Practice` => do nothing because there is 'Centre for' in the sentence

I need a regex which can solve the problem.

I also tried to use the pattern : `"(?=(for.*))(?!(Centre for))"` however it didn't work well

Answer (score 3):

You can use negative lookbehind like this:

```
String str = "This program for all people";
String repl = str.replaceFirst("(?<!Centre) for.*", "");
```

Comment: Uh, your edit now makes it fail if there is more than one space between `Centre` and `for`. Better remove the `+` or add a `\\b` before the space.